# Allow new user's comments on any post in their own question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, new-users, privileges

**Feature Request:**

> Allow new users to comment on any post on their own question.

---

Example of problem:

- User01 posts a question: `What's 1 + 1`
- <s>A swarm of mods quickly close the question</s> Ignore the low quality of *this* particular question - just for explanation purposes.
- @Jon Skeet posts answer: `1 + 1 = 3`
- User01 wants to comment that he `Already tried that and it isn't working for him - see his question`.  However, even though this is User01's own question, he can't post a comment on @Jon Skeet's answer, because he has < 50 rep.

---

**Thoughts**

1. You could add this to a 5 rep privilege, or to the 10 rep `Remove new user restrictions` privilege, rather than allowing it right off the bat.
2. More ideas will be added here upon their creation.

Comment: New users can already comment on their own posts read [How do comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/164200)  The key part is `All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given to their own questions. `

Comment: We already get enough "thanks!" or "i did that, but now I just get a crash on another line" or "I can't read so I tried '1 + 3 = elvis' instead and it doesn't work" comments from 50-rep users…

Comment: Sorry - That must've been a change since I joined.  I seem to remember having this problem.

Comment: This policy has been in place since long before you joined. In the answer @bluefeet linked to, the sentence `All users may leave comments on their own posts and any answers given to their own questions` has been exactly the same since [this July 2012 revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19757/26), and according to your profile you joined 1 year and 1 month ago. (The policy itself is much older, but was phrased slightly differently).

Comment: Huh, well nevermind :)  I thought I'd had this problem myself, and thought I'd see if this could get added.  I must have been mistaken.

Answer (score 17):

It already works that way, please read

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

> Please note that **you can always comment on** your own posts, and **any part of your questions**.

That includes answers to your question.